# Most Economical Personal Computer UPS

Tags: pc, ups

I'm looking for an decent quality UPS with a decent quality battery for a single Linux personal computer. So far, most power outages here have been very short--power lost for mere seconds--so I'm not concerned about continuous running on battery for even several minutes.

The monitor is always off since this is primarily accessed remotely from other boxes. The laser printer is usually on standby, and the PC is pretty much a standard desktop with two hard drives, a network card, and little else.

The ability for the PC to shutdown automatically would be nice, but it's not required since I expect the power to come back up long before the battery runs out.

What would be nice would be to know how long to expect the battery to last, and if it's worth replacing the battery for the inexpensive ones or just buy another cheap unit next year or the year after.

In the past, I've spent $10 on each of these after rebate; nowadays, the lowest price I'm seeing is close to $40-$50.

Comment: You likely will *not* want to attach that laser printer to the UPS, although you may want to invest in a quality surge suppressor for it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting an APC Back-UPS 450VA BN450M costing approximately $50, but it was on sale for $10 off.

I've plugged-in the PC into the surge+battery and left everything else in the original surge protector for now.